# find centroid of hyperpyramid

Tags: geometry, centroid, finite-volume-method

I'm having trouble computing centroid of hyperpyramid (assume we have n points in n dimension). I already search a lot and I find how can calculate triangle and pyramid centroid, but I don't know how can I generalize it and calculate the centroid of a hyperpyramid. Is there any link or book can help me to find an idea about how to compute it?

Comment: You can simply take the average of the vertices, as you would for any other figure.

Comment: @URL it is the estimation of centroid but for my algorithm, I need the exact value.

Comment: Isn’t what I said exact?

Comment: a hyperpyramid (better called a simplex)  needs $n+1$ points in dimension $n$. You will find a lot of information in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you.

Comment: @URL no I read it somewhere that is not as exact as I need.

Comment: @mkafiyan: If by "centroid" you mean "center of mass", then the coordinates of the centroid of a simplex is *exactly* given by the average of the coordinates of the vertices. See the appropriate section of Wikipedia's ["Centroid" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_tetrahedron_and_n-dimensional_simplex). If you mean something else by "centroid", or if perhaps your notion of "hyperpyramid" does not match that of ["simplex"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), then you will need to explain your terms as you understand them.

Comment: @Blue Yes, you are right. I try to prove it by my self and yes it is just the average of coordinates.